# The timing of my Peugeot 308 cc 2010 was torn

Tags: engine, timing-chain, peugeot-308

The timing chain of my Peugeot 308 cc 2010 THP (ep6) was torn, after replacing the parts and repairing the car there was another problem. Now the car is antipollution faile error, it is very weak at the engine rises but it does not move as much as the vehicle, high fuel consumption Is. ... how to find the problem ???

[image]
this a screen shot of diagnosic my car

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: You said the car is now "antipollution faile" ... can you tell us what the codes are for this? What part of it failed? Did you do the work to the car? Are you sure the timing was done correctly? I believe the engine in your 308 is an interference motor, which means to me you may have other issues like bent valves, which would make your engine run like you're describing.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 yes i have some pics of the codes

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 p2261 - p2191 -p2262 - p0243 - p0299